# C++ -- Why should we use explicit in this constructor?

Tags: c++, explicit-constructor

Please refer to [Wikipedia:Strategy Pattern (C++)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#C.2B.2B)

```
class Context
{
    private:
        StrategyInterface * strategy_;

    public:
        explicit Context(StrategyInterface *strategy):strategy_(strategy)
        {
        }

        void set_strategy(StrategyInterface *strategy)
        {
            strategy_ = strategy;
        }

        void execute() const
        {
            strategy_->execute();
        }
};
```

Why it is a good practice to use explicit for the constructor of Context?

Thank you

Comment: If this isn't a good place to use `explicit`, then what is?

Comment: @Potatoswatter:  Anywhere you have a class whose name can't be said aloud in polite company.

Comment: the above remark from James is not to be taken seriously; just for the naive beginner

Comment: To Potatoswatter, just define the constructor without using explicit. -- thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, explicit constructors are always safe, but can be inconvenient.  `explicit` ensures a compilation error should you provide a `StrategyInterface*` where a `Context` is expected.  In doing so, it prevents construction of a temporary `Context`.  This becomes particularly important in certain circumstances, e.g.:

- `Context` takes ownership of the pointed-to `StrategyInterface`, and deletes it in the destructor
- `Context` construction/destruction performs other expensive or inappropriate actions
- it disambiguates some operations implicitly, and makes others ambiguous, where it might be more appropriate to have the programmer consider how to resolve the ambiguity (e.g. should an attempt to compare a `Context` and a `StrategyInterface*` produce a compile-time error, result in comparing `StrategyInterface*`s, `StrategyInterface`s or `Context`s?)

If a `Context` is practically a drop-in-replacement for a `StrategyInterface`, just with some minor logging or other enhancements, then it may be appropriate to allow implicit construction, much as `std::string` can be constructed from `const char*`.  When they're clearly independent things, or when the lifetime of a `Context` should exist beyond any given usage of a `StrategyInterface`, then an explicit constructor's indicated.

(Note: these guidelines are pretty rough - more a starting point than an end - comments welcome)

Answer (score 15):

Because it's generally a good idea to use `explicit` unless you *really* want to allow implicit conversion. Since you're unlikely to use a `Context` object in a situation where you really gain anything from an implicit conversion, you're better off making it `explicit`.