# How can I add a class member if the other class' constructor requires arguments?

Tags: c++

I'm not coding much in C++, so please forgive me if this is trivial.

My class "Foo" looks somewhat like this:

```
class Foo {
    public: Foo(int n) { }
};
```

Another class "Bar" is now supposed to have a class member of type "Foo".

```
class Bar {
    private: Foo f;
};
```

This obviously fails, because there is no constructor for "Foo" that does not require any arguments. However, stuff like `Foo f(1);` fails, too.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Or am I supposed to use a pointer here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Bar {
public:
    Bar():f(0) { }
    explicit Bar(int n):f(n) { }
    private: Foo f;
};
```

write your own `c-tors`, using `initializer-list`, or write `c-tor` without parameters in `Foo`, or use `pointer`, or in `C++11` you can write

```
class Bar {
public:
    private: Foo f = Foo(1);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be handled in 2 different way.

**(1) Provide appropriate argument constructor for `class Foo`**

You can either introduce a no argument constructor `Foo()` or edit the current one accepting default argument, i.e. `Foo(int n = 0)`

**(2) Call constructor of `class Foo` inside the `Bar` with appropriate arugment**

e.g.

```
class Bar {
...
  Bar() : f(0) {}  // (a) pass the argument explicitly 
  Bar(int n) : f(n) {} // (b) receive argument inside Bar()
};
```

Comment: In general, one-argument constructors should be made `explicit` to forbid for unintended conversions, like in your example from `int` to `Bar`. I would use `explicit Bar(int n=0) : Foo(n) {}` in this case.

Comment: @phresnel, I believe that is case to case. Some ppl want to have those conversion intended and some ppl don't want them. I will leave it upto the coder.

Comment: Is there any difference between `Bar() : Foo(0)` and `Bar() : f(0)`?

Comment: `Foo` is not a base class, so you cannot call it's constructor that way. You have to say which member you want to initialize.

Comment: @Niko: yes, there is. `Foo(0)` calls c-tor of base class `Foo`, so it is wrong here. `f(0)` calls c-tor of `f` class member.

Comment: @iammilind: I wrote "in the general case", implying that sometimes you _want_ that behaviour, but personally, outside of math-centric libraries, I almost never see them, and even inside math-centric libs, I only seldomly see them. Actually, I most often see it where not appropriate and where the author just wasn't aware of the reach of the consequences of making it implicit (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4121438/76722). On another note: I realise you either forgot to derive from `Foo`, or have an error and it should be `Bar() : f(0)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a default constructor for Foo or use pointer of Foo in class Bar and set an object later.

Comment: ... or write a `Bar` constructor that soverly constructs a `Foo`, which should be most preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if your Foo needs an argument to construct there are two possibilities:
- Either your Bar will use a **static number** for constructing his own Foo (all Bar will have the same n in Foo)
- Either your Bar's will have **different numbers** in their member Foo. You can then pass a number to Bar constructor as follows:

```
class Bar {
    Bar(int n) : Foo(n) { ... } ;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me.